# Remove emacsclient startup message

Tags: emacsclient

How do I go about removing the message "When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0" when launching emacsclient?

I know it's possible to controll the startup message of emacs when not launched as a daemon by changing the display-startup-echo-area-message function, but it has no effect when I launch emacs with "emacsclient -c"

Answer (score 2):

I checked the code and found there is a `server-after-make-frame-hook`.

So you can add this code in your Emacs init file to workaround this message:

```
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq inhibit-message t)
            (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil (lambda () (setq inhibit-message nil)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you launch emacsclient now, the call blocks the terminal session and releases it only after you kill the frame. Hence the message. If you add the `-n` or `--no-wait` option, the terminal is released immediately and you will not see the message.

Additionally, you might want to use option `-nw` to avoid Emacs creating a new frame.

Create a short shell alias that includes all options that you use. I use `em`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Already tried launching emacsclient with the --no-wait flag though, and the message "When done with this frame, type C-x 5 0" is still there..

Comment: See what happens if you add the '-n' option. It opens the buffer in the existing frame and message should refer to 'C-x #' to close the buffer, but only if the terminal process is waiting for completion. Also, there is a remote chance that this depends on emacs version. You should always give the emacs version and platform (Windows especially has many quirks) you are using.

Comment: I'm running emacs 26.1 on void linux on my raspberry pi 3b+. Tried launching "emacsclient -cn", and the terminal gets released immediately as it should but the message still pops up.. For some reason though the message dissappears if I first kill the frame with "C-x 5 0" and relaunch emacsclient but only if I target a file like this "emacsclient -cn docs.org"

Comment: I had never thought of running emacsclient without a file argument. Normally, you always want to open a file for editing or display.    Running 'emacsclient -cn', I  get the scratch buffer and the message to kill the frame. Doing it, pushes scratch buffer back into the buffer stack (bury-buffer) and displays the previous buffer. Looks like you have hit an edge case where emacs is not working completely predictably.

Comment: I see, totally makes sense! Guess I'm out of luck here. I usually run emacsclient with a file argument but I also use emacs as my file manager using the "ranger" package, running it like this 'emacsclient -cn -e "(ranger)"', you can see in the photo below why I'm dedicated to get rid of the message - it really ruins the aesthetics. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8lbvxg7p5kri4x/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F%202018-09-24%2015%2049%2055.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You could file a bug report to emacs.

Comment: Will look into it! Thanks for taking your time to help me out though, appreciate it. For now I managed to fix it with a ugly hack - when running "ranger" I just pass in an extra random argument that doesn't exist like this 'emacsclient -cn -e "(ranger)" blahblah' and the message is gone.